# Too many triangles

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes

I have a model that I want to export to Roblox studios, however without the realize instance, the model doesn't have any vertices and applying the geometry node[image] causes the model to disappear. But with the realize instance node it has "over 10000 triangles" around 600,000 triangles to be exact, and Roblox has a max of 10k triangles. Is there a way to export the model without realize instance or a good way to reduce the triangle amount.

Comment: Try the `decimate` modifier